# Divorce sentence

Tags: grammar

In the sentence below:

***Jim sent Sally a text message that their marriage was over***

**Jim** - subject

**Sent** - verb

**Sally** - object

**a text message** - object complement?

But what is ***that their marriage was over***

Thanks in advance

Comment: "A text message" is direct object and "Sally" is indirect object. The clause "that their marriage was over" is complement of "text message".

Comment: A message answers: Jim sent what? so it's a direct object. How does Sally become an indirect object?

Comment: "Sally" has the semantic role  of recipient and hence is Oi. Note that in full the Od is "a text message that their marriage was over".

Comment: I appreciate your quick responses. I have more questions but don't want to be a pest. I need to do my own research this was helpful though

Comment: Sally is the indirect object because of course Jim did not send Sally. He sent a message instead.

Comment: You've understood correctly now; it might make it easier in future if you realise that this is a shorter way of saying "Jim sent a text message to Sally".

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, provided it's understood that the PP "to Sally" is not an indirect object.

Comment: Thank you, just a follow up about complements. My understanding is that complements are an important part of the sentence that cannot be left out. But in this example "that their marriage was over" can be left out and the sentence can still make sense. i.e. "Jim sent Sally a text message" Have I misunderstood how complements work?